# ios Instagram api POST Relationship Endpoints using Alamofire - Error

Tags: ios, swift, api, instagram, alamofire

i'm using swift in my app

and i'm trying to post a relationship (Follow) with scope ("follower_list+relationships") using Alamofire

Note: I'm using sandbox users for testing

with this code

```
let userid = "testAccount"
    let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/\(userid)/relationship?access_token=\(INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_Token)&action=follow"

    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

        case .success(let JSON):

        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
        let userModel = response

            print("SUCCESS")
            print(userModel)

        case .failure(let error):

            print("ERROR")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

and also tried this one

```
let userid = "testAccount"
    let urlString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/\(userid)/relationship?access_token=\(INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_Token)"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["action": "follow"]

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

        case .success(let JSON):

        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
        let userModel = response

            print("SUCCESS")
            print(userModel)

        case .failure(let error):

            print("ERROR")
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

BUT still got this message ??

> ERROR
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem .... I've been using account username rather than user-id
there is a difference...my bad

You can get user-id from (search) Endpoint api OR use a web site like
https://smashballoon.com/instagram-feed/find-instagram-user-id/

you put the username and you will get the ID

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to post json I suspect you need to change your encoding with `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`

> The JSONEncoding type creates a JSON representation of the parameters object, which is set as the HTTP body of the request. The Content-Type HTTP header field of an encoded request is set to application/json.

Usage on [github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#http-methods)

Comment: hi Brian..... thanks for responding .....i've changed it to encoding: JSONEncoding.default BUT still get same message !!

Comment: @Nasser To be honest I haven't used this api before but I've just tested you're code with a mocked api and JSON encoding. It returns successfully so your syntax is ok. You don't appear to be getting valid JSON back though. I've also checked the api docs and your request seems to be in the correct format. Are your access token and user id definitely correct?

Comment: Yes the access token and user id i'm passing is correct